# Prove $\cos(\sin x)>\sin(\cos x)$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Prove that $\cos( \sin x)>\sin(\cos x), \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

I have thought that we should consider their difference and show it is positive for all x, so: Let $$A=\cos\sin x-\sin\cos x=\cos\sin x-\cos\left( \frac{\pi}{2}-\cos x\right)$$ but I am unable to move it further. How can we prove that?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351846/show-that-the-equation-cos-sin-x-sin-cos-x-has-no-real-solutions