# How can I prove that $\cos(\sin x)>\sin(\cos x)$ when $0\leq x\leq \pi$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I had a midterm a few days ago,.. and my question goes like this.
Prove $\cos(\sin x)>\sin(\cos x)$ where $0\leq x\leq \pi$

Also, you can use sinx>x when x>0 without proving it.

How can I prove it strictly?

Comment: $sin x$ is smaller then $x$ on for $x$ greater then 0

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351846/show-that-the-equation-cos-sin-x-sin-cos-x-has-no-real-solutions?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: In particular, see the first answer mentioned in user222031's link.

Answer (score 3):

$$\cos\sin{x}-\sin\cos{x}=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\sin{x}\right)-\sin\cos{x}=$$
$$=2\sin\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}-\sin{x}-\cos{x}}{2}\cos\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}-\sin{x}+\cos{x}}{2}>0$$
because by C-S
$$\sin{x}\pm\cos{x}\leq\sqrt{(1^2+1^2)(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)}=\sqrt2<\frac{\pi}{2}$$